# a function that updates the color of a button based on the status of a twitch stream

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, onload

I am wondering, can this function be modified to run when the page loads instead of when the button(s) with class="statusbutton" is clicked?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( ".statusbutton" ).each(function(index){
        $(this).on("click", function(){
            var btnObj = this;

            $.getJSON( 'http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=' + $(this).attr('id') + '&jsonp=?', function(twitchData) {

        if (typeof(twitchData[0]) !== 'undefined' && typeof(twitchData[0].stream_type) !== 'undefined') {
            if (twitchData[0].stream_type == 'live') {
                // live
                $(btnObj).css('background-color', '#00FF00');
            } else {
                // something other than live
                $(btnObj).css('background-color', '#f11');
            }
        }else{
            // no data or invalid data from twitch
            $(btnObj).css('background-color', '#f11');
        }



});

        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a question? I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: there, the thread now reflects my current issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your buttons should retain the ability to trigger the AJAX request when clicked. You can just manually fire the [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) event on your `.statusbutton` buttons right after `DOM ready` and after binding the event handlers.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".statusbutton").each(function(index) {

        $(this).on("click", function() {
            var btnObj = this;
            $.getJSON('http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=' + $(this).attr('id') + '&jsonp=?', function(twitchData) {
                if (typeof(twitchData[0]) !== 'undefined' && typeof(twitchData[0].stream_type) !== 'undefined') {
                    if (twitchData[0].stream_type == 'live') {
                        // live
                        $(btnObj).css('background-color', '#00FF00');
                    } else {
                        // something other than live
                        $(btnObj).css('background-color', '#f11');
                    }
                } else {
                    // no data or invalid data from twitch
                    $(btnObj).css('background-color', '#f11');
                }
            });
        });

    }).trigger('click'); // manually trigger 'click' to initiate AJAX request  

});
```